# Error opening .nc files in R

Tags: r, geospatial, netcdf, netcdf4

I am new to R and NetCDF files. I am trying to open data on surface sea temperatures that are in a .nc file from [here](https://data.nodc.noaa.gov/pathfinder/Version5.3/L3C/). My code is as follows:

```
rm(list=ls())
#install.packages(c("netcdf", "chron", "RColorBrewer", "lattice"))
library(chron)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(lattice)
library(ncdf4)

# set path and filename
ncpath <- "C:/Users/Mihir Sharma/Dropbox/data/"
ncname <- "20140101023458-NCEI-L3C_GHRSST-SSTskin-AVHRR_Pathfinder-PFV5.3_NOAA19_G_2014001_night-v02.0-fv01.0"  
ncfname <- paste(ncpath, ncname, ".nc", sep="")
dname <- "tmp"  # note: tmp means temperature (not temporary)

# open a NetCDF file
ncin <- nc_open(ncfname)
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Error in nc_open(ncfname) : 
Error in nc_open trying to open file C:/Users/Mihir Sharma/Dropbox/1 EPIC/MPA/data/20140101023458-NCEI-L3C_GHRSST-SSTskin-AVHRR_Pathfinder-PFV5.3_NOAA19_G_2014001_night-v02.0-fv01.0.nc
```

I have followed the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20621200/extract-time-series-of-a-point-lon-lat-from-netcdf-in-r) and [here](http://geog.uoregon.edu/bartlein/courses/geog490/week04-netCDF.html). what am I doing wrong?

Many thanks,
Mihir

Comment: Check that the file exists with that path

Comment: more explicitly, what's the output of `file.exists(ncfname)`

Comment: There was a problem with the path- sorry to waste your time and thanks very much for the quick responses!

Comment: Your welcome! Glad you found it. See below for my answer re: path problems when using someone else's code. Upvote and mark it as the answer if it is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path problems when using someone else's code:

```
# set path and filename
ncpath <- "C:/Users/Mihir Sharma/Dropbox/data/"
```

When you're following code on a blog or tutorial, if it's written well, they'll use a platform independent way to describe, but often they won't.

The platform independent way to write a path is:
`file.path("Users", "Mihir Sharma", "Dropbox", "data")`.  This will always use the correct file separator for your Platform, a value stored in `.Platform$file.sep`

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Forward slashes are fine in R on windows

Comment: Thank you, @dww . I edited my assumption about the users platform. `file.path()` is the correct way to construct a path in a platform independent way, so it is now correct.